# Replace scoped session bean for background task

Tags: java, spring, session, scheduled-tasks

In my web-application I have a scoped session bean that is used among other things to keep some credential information required to connect to underlying systems (store a SAML that need to be sent for underlying web-services access).

And I have that bean that does inject the credential at the right place right before the call to the web-serivce.

```
@Autowired
private MyScopedSession myScopedSession;
@Autowired
private SomeWebService someWebService;

public void someCall() {
  ...
  injectSamlPart
  ...
}
```

I want to add background task (one war packaging both web-app + some background task) that runs every hour for this I use a scheduler. Problem is that this background task can't use scoped-session bean (make sense as it is not driven by http request). So I get this kind of error:

```
Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;
```

But I'd like to define a static credential for my background task (e.g. define a system account or so) and thus define a kind of a replacement bean MyScopedSession for the background task so that autowiring works. Is this possible?

For sure what I could do is to define my bean as

```
@Autowired
private SomeWebService someWebService;

public void someCall(MyScopedSession myScopeSession) {
  ...
  injectSamlPart
  ...
}
```

But I don't like this much as I don't want to pass by parameter my credential through all my business services (maybe 10 layers of beans over this up to my background tasks, or up to my rpc calls)

Is there any solution or architecture change that you could recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If your scheduled task are triggered within spring context you can register `Session` scope as `ThreadScope` with below two LOC

```
ConfigurableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
factory.registerScope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
                    new SimpleThreadScope());
```

This should be done at start / initialization of your application (*i.e. background task*) and should be ***exclusive*** to your web-app.

Refer relevant java docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_SESSION), [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#registerScope-java.lang.String-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope-) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusive to your web-app" ?
I did plugged your code at the beginning of my task "run" method but now I have this when accessing from the web:
"WARN SimpleThreadScope does not support destruction callbacks. Consider using RequestScope in a web environment."

Comment: by exclusive I meant that the spring context in web-app should not have this setting. Also you can ignore the warning as you are not using it within web context and docs also mentions the same - `Note: SimpleThreadScope does not clean up any objects associated with it. As such, it is typically preferable to use RequestScope in web environments.`

Comment: No it doesn't work. Once background task have run and so the LOC you gave me was executed then web side doesn't work anymore. All RPC calls fails. There is no exceptions just this WARNING but response is always empty.
Just to be clear in my app I have one spring context and have both some web with servlets and RPC service and I want to have this background task running in the same app.

Comment: This is expected behaviour as I already mentioned in answer that the setting should *not* be applied to web-app. IMO you need to refactor the invocation of background task such that it creates and thus executes in its own spring context; thus not interfering with web-app.

Comment: Then that doesn't solve my problem. I need my service ("someCall") to run as a single instance because I apply in it some custom locking mechanism that need to apply to both calls coming from web and the one coming from background task.

Also if I have fully separated spring context then I simply don't need your trick as I simply can describe MyScopedSession as singleton bean (not session scoped) for the background task.

Comment: Okies. My suggestions are based on best effort basis for the limited information available in question / comments. Would be happy to help if a question is posted with every facets / aspects. Best of Luck!!

Comment: Sure sorry if my question was not explicit enough. You did helped me to understand some part I didn't know about spring.

I think there is no solution as I expect anyway.